# How to target anchor 'Hover' event like in css a:hover in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try this Style but i see a `Glitch` how can i make it correctly, try to `hover` many times to see the `glitch`. I dont need `CSS` solution thanks. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4hh9g068/1/)

Comment: You need to add the code to the question not just a fiddle link

Comment: use the [`:hover`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp) css property

Comment: what is the glitch

Comment: just use css: - https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uuvgwcm3/2/

Comment: already mention, i dont need `css` solution,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) bind two handlers to the element. One for mouse pointer enters and another for leaves the element. Try like following

```
$('.wrap div').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('a').addClass('active');
}, function () {
    $(this).find('a').removeClass('active');
});
```

#### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4hh9g068/2/)